# ng-material-multilevel-menu disable sorting

Tags: angular, sorting, menu, display

I am using ng-material-multilevel-menu which is working fine.But the menu displayed is in sorted order how to disable it
[image]

Here in the image appendix and abbreviation should come in the bottom please let me know is there a parameter which i should set in the menu to disable the sorting and render the menu as same as configuration

Answer (score 0):

According to  [this github discussion](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu/issues/69) it seems this is a known bug with the package:

> when the menu list goes over 10 items, it goes weird with the orders

You gotta wait for a fix, or use a different lib.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the library.

Both [in the main list item](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu/blob/9f2b61c0c712ccbfdab47a5c18b11d4a93e1023d/projects/ng-material-multilevel-menu/src/lib/ng-material-multilevel-menu.component.html#L4) and especially [in the nested list item](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu/blob/9f2b61c0c712ccbfdab47a5c18b11d4a93e1023d/projects/ng-material-multilevel-menu/src/lib/list-item/list-item.component.html#L31) a `keyvalue` pipe is used.

by default, when using the key value pipe [the output array will be ordered by **keys**](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#description).

lucky for us, key value pipe accepts a parameter, a comparer function, thus allowing us to trick it to not order it, by passing a dummy comprarer.

a few minutes ago I issued a pull request, containing a fix to this, when approved & merged by the author, the issue will be resolved.